# Failed sending messages storage android

Tags: java, android, sms, message, android-contentprovider

Just want to ask where does the default android messaging app stores and read failed to send messages. I thought it can be queried on `content://sms/sent` with `STATUS_FAILED` as status. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Telephony.Sms.Outbox`. This class will help you retreive messages which were not sent due to some reason.

use URI as  `content://sms/failed` for retrieving failed sent messages.

Similarly other types can be retrieved as :

```
Inbox = "content://sms/inbox"
Failed = "content://sms/failed"
Queued = "content://sms/queued"
Sent = "content://sms/sent"
Draft = "content://sms/draft"
Outbox = "content://sms/outbox"
Undelivered = "content://sms/undelivered"
All = "content://sms/all"
Conversations = "content://sms/conversations".
```

If you want to retrieve it based on `type`, take a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/provider/Telephony.java#Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.0MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL).

```
        public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL    = 0;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX  = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT   = 2;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT  = 3;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX = 4;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_FAILED = 5; // for failed outgoing messages
        public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_QUEUED = 6; // for messages to send later
```

Comment: Hope that helped you achieve what you wanted :)

Comment: Thanks sir. :) found out that I don't need to have other query for failed messages, I'm currently querying all messages for a certain thread_id, and failed messages are included. Just need to check its type.

Comment: How to get sent message which is in pending state?

Comment: link doesn't work, I keep getting HTTP 503. Also, can you explain how to query for these URI's please? Because I keep getting empty results - see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52205463/997940